# Processing OpenCV and IPCapture library error: Width(0) and height(0) cannot be <= 0

Tags: opencv, processing, ip-camera

I want to get a video from an Ip camera through the IPCapture library and then do a face recognition in this video with the OpenCV library for Processing. If I get only the video from the IP Camera the code works, but if i add also the face rocognition it doesn't work and at the line `opencv.loadImage(cam);`it tells me:Width(0) and height(0) cannot be <= 0.

```java
import ipcapture.*;
import gab.opencv.*;
import java.awt.*;

IPCapture cam;
OpenCV opencv;

void setup() {
  size(512, 384);
  cam = new IPCapture(this, "http://192.168.1.74:90/cam_pic_new.php?  fullscreen", "", "");
  cam.start();
  opencv = new OpenCV(this, 512, 384);
  opencv.loadCascade(OpenCV.CASCADE_FRONTALFACE);
}

void draw() {
  if (cam.isAvailable()) {
    cam.read();
    image(cam, 0, 0);
    opencv.loadImage(cam);
    noFill();
    stroke(0, 255, 0);
    strokeWeight(3);
    Rectangle[] faces = opencv.detect();
    println(faces.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
      println(faces[i].x + "," + faces[i].y);
      rect(faces[i].x, faces[i].y, faces[i].width, faces[i].height);
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**
Thanks for the answers, the code that i tried is this:

```java
import ipcapture.*;
import gab.opencv.*;
import java.awt.*;
IPCapture cam;
OpenCV opencv;

void setup() {
  size(512, 384);
  cam = new IPCapture(this, "http://192.168.1.74:90/cam_pic_new.php", "", "");
  cam.start();
  opencv = new OpenCV(this, 512, 384);
  opencv.loadCascade(OpenCV.CASCADE_FRONTALFACE);
}

void draw() {
  if (cam.isAvailable()) {
    cam.read();
    image(cam, 0, 0);
    if (cam.width > 0 && cam.height > 0) {
      opencv.loadImage(cam);
    }
  }
}
```

The error is at the line `opencv.loadImage(cam);` and it tells me:
Width(0) and height(0) cannot be <= 0

Comment: This part looks suspicious: ```http://192.168.1.74:90/cam_pic_new.php?  fullscreen```. Have you tested this url in the browser ? Does it display the stream ? (wild guess, maybe try ```http://192.168.1.74:90/cam_pic_new.php```) ?

Comment: Yes, it displays the stream and also without "?fullscreen" there is the same error

Comment: Could you do another quick test in a separate sketch ? ```image(loadImage("http://192.168.1.74:90/cam_pic_new.php"),0,0);```

Comment: @george Yes I've done, i tried your code declaring `Pimage image;`and then `image(loadImage("http://192.168.1.74:90/cam_pic_new.php"),0,0);` but there is the error NullPointerException and it tells me: Could not find a method to load http://192.168.1.74:90/cam_pic_new.php

Comment: Tricky! Perhaps the IPCapture library can't decode with the current settings. Does your IP camera allow you to access it's settings and use different encoding formats ?(e.g. JPG/MJPG/X264/etc.) ? If so, it might be worth trying different formats in the hope one will work

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the image has actually loaded any pixels.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34765285/873165) by Processing expert [George Profenza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89766/george-profenza). Specifically this bit:

```java
if(cam.width > 0 && cam.height > 0){//check if the cam instance has loaded pixels
      opencv.loadImage(cam);//send the cam
```

Comment: Yes, i tried but it still doesn't work. Same error.And also if i print the value of cam.width and cam.height they are higher than 0

Comment: @andrsimo Can you please post an updated [mcve] with the changes you've made to your code?

Comment: @andrsimo You can just edit your question to include your latest code.

Comment: Ok I have posted the new software